# Eliminate repeating letters from Strings

Tags: swift

Eliminate repeating letters from Strings in Swift

```
var name1 : String =  "sandeep"
var name2 : String = "warrior"
var name3 : String = name1+name2
var name4 : String = //output should be sndpwio
```

In name 4, I want to eliminate all repeating letters from name 3.

How can I achieve this?

`name1` and `name2` will be coming from the text box from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in 2 steps. First, you need to get the unique characters of both Strings, then you need to compare the characters of the two Strings and only keep the ones that are not present in both.

The `String` extension `getUniqueCharacters` returns an array of the unique characters of the `String` it was called on (you can use this to get rid of the repeating characters of a String, such as 'e' in "sandeep").

```
var name1 = "sandeep"
var name2 = "warrior"

extension String{
    func getUniqueCharacters()->[Character]{
        var characterCounts = [Character:Int]()
        self.characters.forEach{ char in
            if characterCounts[char] != nil {
                characterCounts[char]! += 1
            } else {
                characterCounts[char] = 1
            }
        }
        return self.characters.filter{characterCounts[$0]! == 1}
    }
}
```

Then you just call above function on the concatenated Strings and you're done.

```
let name3 = name1+name2
let name4 = name3.getUniqueCharacters().map{String($0)}.joined()
print(name4) //sndpwio
```

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you just ignored `name1` and `name2` and worked with `name3`.

Comment: You're right, simplified my solution, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSCountedSet` to count hold many times each character appears, then filter for those that appear only once:

#### Swift 3

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: name3.characters.map { $0 })
let name4 = String(name3.characters.filter { countedSet.count(for: $0) == 1 })
```

#### Swift 4

In Swift 4, `String` is a `Collection` of characters again so you can shorten code to this:

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: name3.map { $0 })
let name4 = name3.filter { countedSet.count(for: $0) == 1}
```

Comment: Your `Swift3` code doesn't compile due to the error _"Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Character' (0x11ce5e340) to 'NSObject' (0x6000000541a8).
"_

Comment: Test and run without problems on both Mac OS X and Linux

Comment: I received the mentioned error when trying to run your code on `macOS` using `Swift3` in a playground.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with your version of Xcode then. Here's a snippet on the [IBM Swift Sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599975dda5f97c4ee18da7bf) (Linux)

Comment: An interesting example, your code works on the actual projects, but causes error in the Playground.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't write it in Playground. The Xcode 8 playground gave me an error but Xcode 9 (beta) Playground did not. It works in a project for both versions though

Comment: As you know, `Character` is not ObjC-bridgeable. So it seems `NSCountedSet` holds `_SwiftValue` instead. I really doubt if we can rely on the behavior of  `_SwiftValue` when contained in an `NSCountedSet`.

Comment: It can be initialized from `Set<AnyHashable>` which leads me to believe that it only a `Hashable` type. And `Character` conforms to `Hashable`. I'll gladly edit this answer if you can find one counter example

Comment: `NSCountedSet` is an Objective-C class and it internally treats the elements as `NSObject`. As far as I tested, `[aSwiftValue hash]` returns the the same value as `originalSwiftValue.hashValue` when the `originalSwiftValue` is `Hashable`, but I do not know if it is a guaranteed behavior or not. Until someone clarifies it's safe, I would not recommend your solution. For me, _use until counter example found_ is not a safe way to go.

Comment: If Apple makes it available in Swift, it must be safe for use in Swift, unless they say otherwise in their documentation. Let's just agree to disagree

Comment: David, I'm guessing you're not importing Foundation.

Comment: And the NSObject issues OOPer talks about are resolved by casting it to String:  `let set = NSCountedSet(array: characters.map { String($0) } )`

Comment: @DavidBerry I am importing it, that is not the issue. As OOPer confirmed, the issue exists in playgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str : String = "sandeepwarrior"

// convert String to array
let letters = str.characters.map { String($0) }  

// get  duplicates
let duplicates = Array(Set(letters.filter({ (i: String) in letters.filter({ $0 == i }).count > 1})))

// remove duplicates from str
for item in duplicates {
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: item, with: "")
}

print(str)
```